# ajax - request data from multiple files on one page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to run multiple Ajax functions on load in a single page which will get data from two different php pages. Both the Ajax functions will then print the retrieved data onto the page from which the ajax function was called. The problem I encountered was that the last function call which I make from the Ajax overrides the first function call, and so only the second function result is showed.

The code for one of the Ajax function (since both of the are very similar to each other):

```
function favorite_track_request(str){

switch(str){
case 'next_track':
    var feed = 'require_fav_track_info';
    var offset = track_currentOffset + 5;
    if(offset > max_track_range){
        offset -= 5;
    }
    break;
case 'prev_track':
    var feed = 'require_fav_track_info';
    var offset = track_currentOffset - 5;
    if(offset < 0){
       offset = 0;
    }
    break;
default:
    var feed = 'require_fav_track_info';
    var offset = 0;
}



request = new ajaxRequest()

request.open("GET", "scripts/"+feed+".php?offset="+offset, true)


request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4){
        if(this.status == 200){
            if(this.responseText != null){
               if(request.responseText){
                   document.getElementById('fav_tracks').innerHTML = request.responseText;
               }
           }else alert("No data recieved");
        }else {
           alert("Ajax error: "+this.statusText);
        }
    }
}

request.send(null); 
    track_currentOffset = offset;
}
```

This ajax would then print to `<div id="fav_tracks"></div>`, however this gets overridden because another call (similar to the Ajax above) is made and that overrides the previous one. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you fire off 2 AJAX requests? How would they know not to "override" one another? I think you need to explain better when this function is called (what event on your page), how often/fast it's called, and what you really want to happen. Also, you could try using `document.getElementById('fav_tracks').innerHTML += request.responseText;` (notice the **+** character) to append to the div's text, not just overwrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a data handler "class" to manage just such a thing. You are right, the one overrides the other. I haven't investigated it, but it's probabably because your are re-assigning the onEvent that AJAX uses.

Below is the class I built (I know, it's not JQuery... it works). What it does is uses timeouts to "know" when to fire the second and third async request. There probably is a JQuery function that does the same thing.

You would call this by using the below for each AJAX call (giving each call a unique var name):

```
dataHandler = new DataHandler("[name of datafile to call]");
dataHandler.query['[myQueryName]'] = 'myValue' //this is an Object used to build a query string, if needed, so use as many data pairs as you need
dataHandler.asynchronous(myOnReadyStateChangeFN);//put the fn you want to use for readystatechange as a reference... do not includ the ()
```

Here's the "class":

```
function DataHandler(dataFile){
    this.dataFile = dataFile;
    dataInProgress = false;
    this.query = new Object();

        this.asynchronous = function(fn){
        var thisFunction = this.asynchronous
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*100001);
        var query, timeOutFunctionString;
        if(this.dataInProgress){
            timeOutFunctionString = callingObjectName+".asynchronous("+fn+")";
            this.thisTimeout = setTimeout(timeOutFunctionString,500);
        }else{
            dataInProgress = true;
            this.assignRequestObject.xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                fn();
                dataInProgress = false;
                return;
            };
        }
        query = this.dataFile + '?r=' + rand;
        for (var key in this.query) query = query + '&' + key + '=' + this.query[key];

        //console.info("DataHandler.asynchronous\nquery = "+query+'\nthis.dataFile = ' + this.dataFile);
        this.assignRequestObject.xmlHttp.open('GET', query, true);
        this.assignRequestObject.xmlHttp.send(null);
    };
    this.AssignRequestObject = function() {
        try { this.xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest() } catch (e) {
            try { this.xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP") } catch (e) {
                try { this.xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") } catch (e) {
                    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    };
    this.assignRequestObject = new this.AssignRequestObject();
};
```